# Highlight different events with different colors in a day (cell) ASP.NET calendar

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, calendar

I am working on a page where I need to highlight different events in a day with different colors in a ASP.NET Calendar Cell. The events are store in a database with a start date column.

For example, if we have two different events for today, the cell should display half green and half red color. If there are three events for today, it would 1/3 green, 1/3 red, 1/3 blue in the cell for today.

In addition, currently I use tooltip in jquery to hover a cell, it would display a tooltip above the cell. How to handle this when we have different events in one cell?

All the answers are very much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I could answer my own question. I used the DayRender event, and in that event, I did a select statement to get all the events information for each day of the calendars. I could get the number of events in one day from the select statement. Based on how many events on a day, I will add how many divs into the day cell; and based on number of events in one day, I can set the width of the div. In addition, when I added the divs, I added the class for the each div so that I can change the colors of each div.

Answer (score 1):

The DayRender event on the calendar gives you full control of the cell.  The calendar essentially amounts to a table structure; you will have to use DIV's within the container with a given fixed height and manually apply this logic.  It may also be possible on the client, but I think the easiest is the server.  It won't be easy, but should be possible.

Comment: +1 - There is an example here showing how you can style the cell in the DayRender event - http://odetocode.com/Articles/223.aspx

Comment: Yes that's good, the issue here will be styling the cell in two or three ways, which can be done by writing custom HTML...

Comment: I cheated and used a specific background image for each of the cases mentioned :-)